# Why do the two variables point to different location when they are assigned same value outside the range [-5,256]?

Tags: python, memory-management

Consider the below code.

```
x = 10
y = 10
print(id(x))
print(id(y))
```

Output:

140710803641440

140710803641440

Now, give same values outside the range [-5,256]

```
x = 257
y = 257
print(id(x))
print(id(y))
```

Output:

2366730643376

2366730642864